# How do i sort json response in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to do a sorting of json response by start time in my php?

PHP

```
$sql =  "SELECT teamone,teamtwo,s_name,start,end,venue FROM matches as A right join schedule as B ON A.m_id = B.m_id";
 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
array_push($response, array("start"=>$row[3],"end"=>$row[4],"venue"=>$row[5], "teamone"=>$row[0], "teamtwo"=>$row[1], 
"s_name"=>$row[2]));

}

echo json_encode (array("schedule_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my json output

```
{"schedule_response":[{"start":"2016-11-21 08:00:00","end":"2016-11-21 08:30:00","venue":"ccc",
"teamone":"aaa","teamtwo":"ddd","s_name":"Futsal"},
{"start":"2016-11-22 08:00:00","end":"2016-11-22 08:30:00","venue":"bbb",
"teamone":"Winner 1","teamtwo":"Winner 2","s_name":"Futsal"},
{"start":"2016-11-21 08:30:00","end":"2016-11-21 09:00:00","venue":"aaa",
"teamone":"bbb","teamtwo":"ccc","s_name":"Futsal"},
{"start":"2016-11-21 12:00:00","end":"2016-11-21 12:30:00","venue":"hehe",
"teamone":"hehehe","teamtwo":"hahahaha","s_name":"Basketball"}]}
```

How can i sort this by making the earliest start time the first in the response?

Comment: try adding `ORDER BY start DESC` to your sql statement

Comment: you don't *sort JSON* - you sort the data from which you *generate* the JSON - best with an `ORDER BY`, as Blinkydamo suggested.

Comment: Sort the array before encoding it. You can do that either by sorting the query result (@Blinkydamo commented on how), or by sorting the resulting array (you can use php sort function - or just make your own).

Comment: Wow thank you very much @Blinkydamo